# Firebase call inside useEffect is not returning data properly

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a component `Photo.js` responsible for making a call to to my firestore and rendering the returned data. The returned data is set to a state variable `venues`. 
This data is then mapped over and rendered to the browser, however I'm getting the following error in the browser:

> Cannot read properties of null (reading 'map')

And when I console log the state variable `venues`, it's being returned as `null`. 
If I comment out the code responsible for mapping out the returned data (below), my webpage renders without problem - and if I uncomment the same code and save, the firebase call works and the data is rendered:

```
            {venues.map((item) => {
                return(<img src = {item.photoUrl}/>)
            })}
```

Here's the ***Photos*** component controlling the firebase call:

```
import { useState,useEffect } from 'react'
import {getVenues} from '../../services/firebase.js'

const Photo = () => {
    const [ venues,setVenues ] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('it got here')
        async function getAllVenues(){
            const response = await getVenues()
            await setVenues(response)
        }
        getAllVenues()
    },[])

    console.log(venues)
    return(
        <div className = 'venueCard-container'>
            {venues.map((item) => {
                return(<img src = {item.photoUrl}/>)
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Photo
```

...and the the firebase functions in ***services/firebase.jss***

```
import {firebase} from '../firebaseConfig'

export async function getVenues() {
    const response = await firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection('venues')
    .get()
    return response.docs
        .map((venue) => ({...venue.data()}))
}
```

I'm thinking this is some sort of async problem - the component is rendering before the firebase call has returned the data. Suggestions?

Comment: `useState(null)` For the first render, you've set the state to null. Make sure to check for that before calling `.map` on it. For example, `{venues && venues.map((item) => {` Or, make the initial state an empty array, so that it has a map function.

Answer (score 1):

```
const [ venues,setVenues ] = useState(null)
```

You've set the initial value of the state to be null, so that's what it will be on the first render. Some time later the data will finish loading and you'll render again, but until that time, your component needs to work with the initial state. You could check for null and render nothing:

```
return(
    <div className = 'venueCard-container'>
        {venues && venues.map((item) => {
            return(<img src = {item.photoUrl}/>)
        })}
    </div>
)
```

...or you could render a placeholder:

```
if (!venues) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
} else {
    return (
        <div className = 'venueCard-container'>
            {venues.map((item) => {
                return(<img src = {item.photoUrl}/>)
            })}
        </div>
    )
  );
}
```

...or you could make the initial state be an empty array, which means it will always have a `.map` method even before loading has finished:

```
const [ venues,setVenues ] = useState([])
```